# Definition of Topological space (Tao's Analysis II vs Other)

Tags: general-topology, definition

I am reading Tao's Analysis II. The definition a topological space he gives is the following:

[image]

My question regards the choice to let $\mathcal{F}$ be a strict subset of the power set. As far as I understand, the topology could easily the whole of $2^X$ right? Isn't this what is called a discrete topology? So why does Tao require it to be a strict subset? Is he trying to avoid some trivial topologies?

Comment: He's just using $\subset$ to denote a non-strict subset. You're right, if $\mathcal{F} = 2^X$ then it is the discrete topology which is an important (counter)example.

Comment: $\subset$ here just means a subset, exactly like its $\LaTeX$ name. The notation for a strict subset is $\subsetneq$, and $\subseteq$ is another symbol which *also* just means a subset, but perhaps where you are emphasizing the possibility that the subset might be the whole set. I didn't do it! It is very unfortunate that this notational convention is not consistent with the usual meaning of $\lt$ and $\leq$. Wikipedia comments on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#%E2%8A%82_and_%E2%8A%83_symbols The solution, of course, is to never use $\subset$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right of course:
the topology can be the discrete topology:

$\{X, \tau\}, \;\tau=2^X$.

it can also be the trivial topology:

$\tau=\{X,\emptyset\}$.

so in the definition it should be $\tau\subseteq 2^X$.

Basically we use the powerset to show that certain classes of sets (topology, $\sigma$-algrbras, etc.) are not empty.

Comment: You don't really address the main issue which is that some authors use $\subset$ to mean the same as $\subseteq$. Therefore, there is no typo in the definition.

Comment: I am using Suppe's definition: $A\subseteq B \iff x\in A\rightarrow x\in B$ and $A\subset B\iff x\in A \rightarrow x\in B \land A\neq B$.

Comment: That's fine, but as I said, some authors use $\subset$ to mean what you mean by $\subseteq$.